# Propagate spring transaction to sibling call

Tags: java, spring, transactions

Consider I have following spring beans

**CompositeService**:

```
@Service
public class CompositeService {

    @Resource
    private ServiceA serviceA;

    @Resource
    private ServiceB serviceB;

    public ResultBean compositeMethod() {
        ResultBean result = new ResultBean();
        result.setA(serviceA.getA());
        result.setB(serviceB.getB());
        return result;
    }

}
```

**ServiceA**:

```
@Service
public class ServiceA {

    @Transactional
    @Cacheable
    A getA() {
        // calls DAO layer and makes a query to the database
    }

}
```

**ServiceB**:

```
@Service
public class ServiceB {

    @Transactional
    @Cacheable
    B getB() {
        // calls DAO layer and makes a query to the database
    }

}
```

The cacheable aspect has a higher order

The problem with this code is that it will start two transactions (and take two connections from the pool) in case of cache-miss in both services.
Can I configure Spring to use the same transaction in this use case?
I.E. propagate the transaction from *ServiceA* to the *CompositeService* and after that down to *ServiceB*?

I cannot set the *CompositeService* as transactional because I do not want to start a transaction (and borrow a connection from pool) in case of cache-hit both in *ServiceA* and *ServiceB*

Comment: It will only work if the enclosing method (in the `CompositeService` ) is transactional. Why would it be a problem to checkout a connection for a couple of milliseconds, if those are the things you are worried about IMHO you are worrying about the wrong things.

Comment: @M.Deinum in my particular case the database is deployed in a data center in another region with a 300ms latency between java application and database

Comment: So? You have a connection pool so the connections are already there. The only thing that happens is a connection is checked out from the pool. Nothing else. That should just take ~ 1ms...

Comment: @M.Deinum validation query (like _select 1 from dual_) takes 300ms to execute. I do understand that I can remove the validation query, use the decent pool and handle the appropriate exceptions in my dao layer - but the question is whether _Spring_ can do this for me or not?

Comment: One thing you could try is wrapping your `DataSource` in a [`LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.html) which will only obtain a `Connection` when needed. This is when the first `Statement` is created.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks a lot - it worked for me. If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it. If you don't want to / don't have time I'll do it myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring will only propagate a transaction if everything is under the same transaction. So the short answer is that you should annotate your `CompositeService` with `@Transactional`.

```
@Service
public class CompositeService {

    @Transactional
    public ResultBean compositeMethod() {
        ResultBean result = new ResultBean();
        result.setA(serviceA.getA());
        result.setB(serviceB.getB());
        return result;
    }
}
```

Generally this is fast enough as it only does a checkout from the underlying connection pool. However if you experience latency or don't always need a connection you can wrap your actual `DataSource` in a [`LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.html). This will obtain a `Connection` when first needed.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you can annotate the *compositeMethod* with `@Transactional` as well. The default propagation level of a transaction is set to Required

> Support a current transaction, create a new one if none exists.

So even though its not exactly what you asked, the transaction demarcation starts with the compositeMethod, but it should be exactly the semantics you want.

Comment: I cannot set the CompositeService as transactional because I do not want to start a transaction (and borrow a connection from pool) in case of cache-hit both in ServiceA and ServiceB

Comment: mhm, your problem is much more interesting that it meets an eye on a first look